# jwtAuth login with laravel 5.2 on custom field

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, jwt

I'm trying to implement **token based authentication in laravel 5.2**. I'm following [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/token-based-authentication-for-angularjs-and-laravel-apps) blog to implement. After doing all the things, when I'm going to test, I got 500 error. On debugging the code, I found that **jwt calls a function (`once($credentials)`)** in `vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/Providers/Auth/IlluminateAuthAdapter.php` file. And `once()` function is not defined in any file of jwt-auth package. If anyone have faced same problem before and knows the solution, it will be appreciated.

Comment: Please add the full 500 error.